# Levenshtein distance giving strange values

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

Here's a string `T`:

> 'men shirt team brienne funny sarcasm shirt features graphic tees mugs babywear much real passion brilliant design detailed illustration strong appreciation things creative br shop thousands designs found across different shirt babywear mugs funny pop culture abstract witty many designs brighten day well day almost anyone else meet ul li quality ***short sleeve*** crew neck shirts 100 cotton soft durable comfortable feel fit standard size doubt l xl available li li sustainability label company conceived belief textiles industry start acting lot responsibly made cotton li li clothing printed using state art direct garment equipment crack peel washed li li graphic tee designs professionally printed unique design look great make someone smile funny cute vintage expressive artwork li ul'

I've highlighted a part of the above string since the above is a preprocessed version of a string, and thus may be difficult to read.

I'm getting the following values:

`fuzz.partial_ratio('short sleeve', T)` gives `50`

`fuzz.partial_ratio('long sleeve', T)` gives `73`

`fuzz.partial_ratio('dsfsdf sleeve', T)` gives `62`

`fuzz.partial_ratio('sleeve', T)` gives `50`

I'm very confused by this. Shouldn't the first and fourth values be 100? Surely I'm missing something but I cannot figure it out.

EDIT: Here's another example that I run after uninstalled python-Levenshtein library:

> 'first succeed way wife told v 2 long sleeve shirt id 1084 first succeed way wife told v 2 long sleeve shirt design printed quality 100 long sleeve cotton shirt sports gray 90 cotton 10 polyester standard long sleeve shirts fashion fit tight fitting style please check size chart listed additional image feel free contact us first sizing questions satisfaction 100 guaranteed shirts usually ship business day ordered noon est next business day ordered noon est long sleeve shirts 100 cotton standard shirt fashion fit combined shipping multiple items'

`fuzz.partial_ratio('long sleeve', T)` gives 27

`fuzz.partial_ratio('short sleeve', T)` gives 33

`fuzz.partial_ratio('sleeveless', T)` gives 40

`fuzz.partial_ratio('dsfasd sleeve', T)` gives 23

Unfortunately the problem doesn't seem to be exclusive to python-Levenshtein library.

Comment: Are you sure you are using levenshtein correctly? It should be used to similar length strings. If you are looking for 'similar' string in whole bunch of text i would do a search with a 'window' and move it by one character at a time.
Also if you compare that paragraph with any string in `fuzzy`, this is not search operation, this is "how close" these string are to each other operation.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything at all. There looks to be a subtle bug in the library. Trying to figure out exactly what is going on.

Comment: Yeah he is right it should be 100 after aligning the blocks. I will debug with code base and check it out to see where its going wrong or if there is an assumption in the function.

Answer (score 3):

There is a really strange and subtle bug in the `fuzzywuzzy` library somewhere.

If we run the following

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

fuzz.partial_ratio('funny', 'aa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa funny aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaayaaaa auaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaffaaaaaaa aaaaa aaayaaaa auaa funny aaaa aaaaaa')
```

it returns `0`

Whereas if we remove a single letter from the start of this string:

```
fuzz.partial_ratio('funny', 'a aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa funny aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaayaaaa auaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaffaaaaaaa aaaaa aaayaaaa auaa funny aaaa aaaaaa')
```

It returns `100`

(sorry about the long and horrible strings. I've tried to reduce it to as simple a string as possible, but I can't seem to see the logic driving this bug)

There seems to be [similar bug reports](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/issues/279) on Github.

Installing `python-Levenshtein` seemed to fix my example above (fuzzywuzzy reverts to `difflib` if `python-Levenshtein` isn't installed), but doesn't change your original example.

With `python-Levenshtein` installed, I can reduce your example to:

```
fuzz.partial_ratio('sleeve', 's l e e v sleeve e ')
```

which return `50`.

Removing the first letter from the longer string:

```
fuzz.partial_ratio('sleeve', 'l e e v sleeve e ')
```

returns `100`.

This provides some sort of hints as to what may be going on, but I suspect it will require a deep dive into `python-Levenshtein` to figure out.

My recommendation? File a bug report. And then find another library to compare strings. [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) could be a suitable alternative.

UPDATE:

I think the bug may be related to the use of `opcodes` from the `python-Levenshtein` library:

```
from Levenshtein import opcodes

opcodes('sleeve', 's l e e v sleeve e ')
```

Returns:

```
[('equal', 0, 1, 0, 1),
 ('insert', 1, 1, 1, 2),
 ('equal', 1, 2, 2, 3),
 ('insert', 2, 2, 3, 4),
 ('equal', 2, 3, 4, 5),
 ('insert', 3, 3, 5, 6),
 ('equal', 3, 4, 6, 7),
 ('insert', 4, 4, 7, 8),
 ('equal', 4, 5, 8, 9),
 ('insert', 5, 5, 9, 12),
 ('equal', 5, 6, 12, 13),
 ('insert', 6, 6, 13, 19)]
```

When used in `fuzzywuzzy`, this is clearly not the intended result, even though these are one set of minimum edit operations. In `fuzzywuzzy`, priority should be placed on continuous blocks, whereas the formal definition of Levenshtein distance doesn't give priority to continuous vs non-continuous blocks (at least not to my understanding). Note that `difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes()` gives a different result.

I suspect some very careful thought is going to be needed to fix this bug and get it right.

Comment: The bug has to be with python-Levenshtein sequence matcher, as I am able to replicate this only with the package installed.

Comment: I have python levenshtein installed as well. And thanks for the answer! I tested some of these edge cases with functions from python levenshtein and have been getting some funky results there as well. I'll edit the question after I wake up

Comment: Yes, it boils down to the assumption that the minimum edit operations will prioritise continuous blocks, which isn't the case. As long as the letters from the shorter word are present in order in the longer string (even spaced out amongst other words), then you will have issues using fuzzywuzzy. Maybe try RapidFuzz as an alternative.

Comment: I've also encountered this bug in some form or another with most of the functions. process.extract_one also does some interesting things with certain strings where it doesn't seem to be adhering to the true definition of Levenshtein distance. Like @the23Effect states only with python-Levenshtein installed.

Comment: The reality is that Levenshtein distance is a poor metric to use when comparing a short string with a much larger section of text. An algorithm with explicit gap penalties is more appropriate, such as Smith-Waterman. I'm not sure what the solution is with the fuzzywuzzy library. You don't want to break backwards compatibility, but using Levenshtein distance introduces way too many problematic edge cases.

Comment: @AndrewGuy: I'm basically trying to identify an attribute value from a block of text (e.g. the description of a clothing item), as I've given in the question. So if the attribute is the sleeve length, then potential values could be long sleeve, short sleeve, sleeveless, 3/4 sleeve, etc. The tagged attribute value for a particular item would then be the one which has highest fuzzy similarity (lowest Levenshtein distance) to the text block. So from what you're saying, there's a better alternative to Levenshtein/fuzzywuzzy for this purpose?

Comment: @the23Effect: I uninstalled python-Levenshtein and again get a similar problem. I've added an edit to the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea behind the algorithm is to find the best matching substring in a longer string. However, there are a couple of issues with the way this is done in FuzzyWuzzy. In the following description of the algorithm `s1` refers to the shorter string, `s2` to the longer string and `s2_substr` to a substring of s2.
They implement this algorithm in the following steps:

1. They use the Longest Common Subsequence algorithm to find the longest common substrings of `s1` in `s2`
2. They use the starting index of these common subsequences to extract substrings of length `s1_len` from `s2`. This substring `s2_substr` can be shorter than `s1_len` when it is placed at the end of `s2`.
3. They iterate over those substrings `s2_substr` and compare each of them to `s1` using a normalized InDel-Distance (like Levenshtein Distance but without Substitutions)

I am aware of the following shortcomings of this implementation

1. When python-Levenshtein is used, FuzzyWuzzy uses it both to find the Longest Common Subsequences and calculate the Similarity. However, the implementation python-Levenshtein is using to find the Longest Common Subsequence is known to be broken (see [here](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/issues/16)) and I am not aware of a simple fix to this. Someone proposed a fix, which however only fixes this one case and introduces problems in different cases. (This is the original issue you described)
2. When python-Levenshtein is not used difflib is used to calculate the Longest Common Subsequence is calculated using difflib. However, as described [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/issues/279) FuzzyWuzzy does not disable the auto junk heuristic, which leads to incorrect results when the strings have a big length difference. I just created a PR to fix this: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/pull/303, but the repository is not really maintained actively and SeatGeek appears fine with many of the shortcomings, since it works well enough for their use case. (This is the issue with difflib you added later)
3. The similarity ratio in itself is flawed. It assumes, that the best matching substring `s2_substr` always starts at the starting point of one of the longest common subsequences. While this is true in many cases, this is not always the case. (You did not run into this issue and I did not see a bug report on this in FuzzyWuzzy or RapidFuzz yet. The result only differs a lot in some very specific edge cases most users probably do not run into often)

Which algorithm is better suited largely depends on your needs. A first simple solution is to replace FuzzyWuzzy with my library [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz). This fixes the issues with the LCS algorithm I described. However, it uses the same algorithm as FuzzyWuzzy to calculate the similarity, so the third issue exists as well. I am searching for a better algorithm (for more details check the [following question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136529/calculating-the-string-similarity-of-an-optimal-alignment)).
As noted by Andrew Guy the Smith-Waterman distance could be an alternative as well. However, it has some big differences to `fuzz.partial_ratio`:

1. it uses the uniform Levenshtein distance (Insertions/Deletions/Substitutions all have a weight of 1), while fuzz.partial_ratio uses the InDel Distance. In case that's important to you, it can probably be adapted to use the InDel distance by giving Substitutions a weight of 2 when implementing it.
2. fuzz.partial_ratio always takes a substring with the length `s1_len`, while the Smith Waterman algorithm searches for the best aligned substring, without caring about the length of it. This is not bad, you should just be aware of it. One disadvantage is, that it is harder to normalize the result (bring it to a similarity score between 0 and 100), since the length of the substring is not known. This is not really a problem, since you can just search for the lowest distance instead of the highest similarity.

The reason I am not using the Smith-Waterman algorithm in RapidFuzz to calculate the fuzz.partial_ratio, is that I want it to be a direct replacement for the implementation in FuzzyWuzzy. However, I am planning to add the Smith-Waterman algorithm in the future as well.

Comment: Great answer, and it's clear you have a much better understanding of the intricacies of the problem than I do. I should note that my suggestion of the Smith-Waterman algorithm comes from my background in biological sequence analysis, which is a little different to NLP. One important point is that it doesn't treat word boundaries differently to any other character, so may give odd results when used in a NLP setting.